# avoid 'IF' , if possible to check different condition in where clause 

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query in which column used in where clause in changed depending on the parameter 
of the stored procedure:

```
select * from tableName where col2=someValue
```

above query runs if inputparameter is 'X' and if 
it is 'Y' then

```
select * from tableName where col2=someValue
```

I can write a if block checking for the condition and then executing the respective query.
but i am trying to combine these  two query into one.
Please help.

Comment: Looks like a cut & paste error to me.  They're the same query.

Comment: how are the two queries different?

Comment: I believe that the OP is asking if input parameter is 'X' then SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=value AND if input parameter is 'Y' then SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2=value

Comment: @Niraj: has your question been answered ?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * from tableName 
WHERE  ( inputparameter = 'X' AND  col1=someValue )
    OR ( inputparameter = 'Y' AND  col2=someValue )
       ;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
WHERE :SomeValue = DECODE(:InputParameter, 'X', Col1, 'Y', Col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableName 
where  1 = CASE
            when inputparameter = 'X'
            AND  col1=someValue 
            THEN 1
            when inputparameter = 'Y'
            AND  col2=someValue 
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
           END
```

Comment: plz,schurik can you  please explin the query.1 = case part

Comment: '1 = CASE' combined with 'ELSE 0' makes the SQL return nothing if inputparameter is something other than 'X' or 'Y'.

Comment: @NirajChoubey: I was also struggling with this answer, but I understood it when I compared it to wildplasser's answer.

Comment: The `CASE` statement has to return a value. So they have gone with the strategy of returning `1` when its a good row and anything else otherwise. So in the where clause they compare the result of the `CASE` to `1`. There is nothing special about the `1 =`, it could have been anything, just as long as it matched the `THEN` values. I like the `DECODE` answer the best.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions built around conditions in "where" part of query are working, but not optimal from performance point of view. Therefore, if `tableName` is really big then better variant is building dynamic sql or implement this case as two separate query.

E.g.

```
create or replace procedure GetSomething(
  inputParameter in varchar2, 
  someValue      in varchar2  
) 
  return sys_refcursor
as
  cRet sys_refcursor;
begin

  if(inputParam = 'X') then
    open cRet for 
       select * from tableName where col1 = someValue
    ;
  elsif(inputParam = 'Y') then
    open cRet for 
       select * from tableName where col2 = someValue
    ;
  else
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid value of inputParameter.'); 
  end if;

end;
```

Of course, both columns must be indexed for good performance.